# Ubuntu 9.10 vs 10.04

Tags: linux, 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-9.10

I'm looking at Ubuntu as a choice to linux. 64bit and was wondering what difference there is in both 9.10 to 10.04. I have tried the 10.10 version - but found it was sort of sluggish compared to 10.04 - no idea why. But what is better and has less overhead? Ubuntu 9.10 or 10.04?

Comment: Should this be on AskUbuntu.com?

Answer (score 0):

10.04.2. It's the best release since 9.04, and before that, 8.04.1. Both 9.10 and 10.10 were not particularly solid releases.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference IMO is that 10.04 has  [long term support](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/desktop/long-term-support) so it will be supported well past this year.